# Android Studio XML layout design preview not available

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know what happened, but today when I opened Android Studio the "split-screen" of the editing layout (Preview -half screen XML and the other half was the device preview-) was missing.

[image]
- No preview option

[image]
- The "component tree" tab was added automatically, yesterday I did not have this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're in the **Design** tab, switch to the **Text** tab in the lower left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio offers an advanced layout editor that allows you to
>   drag-and-drop widgets into your layout and preview your layout while
>   editing the XML.

Within the layout editor, you can switch between the Text view, where you edit the XML file as text, and the Design view. Just click the appropriate tab at the bottom of the window to display the desired editor.

Read Official guideline about **[Using the Layout Editor](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/studio-layout.html)**